# EPS inclusion from texmf-tree not working

Tags: includegraphics, epstopdf, texmf, kpathsea

## Introduction

I have a project-specific texmf tree, which I use for package development, which is called `texmf-project`. This tree is correctly registered as an auxtree in texlive on debian 11. In my document, I need to include eps graphics, which I want to reside in the `texmf-project` tree. On compiling with

```bash
$ pdflatex --shell-escape mwe.tex
 ... 
 ! Package pdftex.def Error: File `logo-eps-converted-to.pdf' not found: using draft setting.
 ...
```

## Setup

My file structure looks like this:

```
<project-directory>
 |- texmf-project
 |   |- tex
 |       |- images
 |           |- logo.eps
 |- mwe.tex
```

and the MWE is

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
    \includegraphics[height=3cm]{logo.eps}
\end{document}
```

If you need an eps for testing, just download the eps from [this link](https://www.logotypes101.com/logo/comune-di-roma-s-p-q-r-).

## Debugging steps taken

### ensure the logo file can be found

To ensure, that the logo file is actually found by kpathsea, I ran (from the )

```bash
$ kpsewhich logo.eps
./texmf-project/tex/images/logo.eps
```

which correctly found the file.

### ensure epstpdf works correctly

If I place `logo.eps` alongide `mwe.tex` in the `<project directory>`, then `pdflatex` runs without error and generates `logo-eps-converted-to.pdf`.

### ensure `\includegraphics` works from the `texmf-project`

If I replace the eps file with a jpg inside, i.e. put `./texm-project/tex/images/logo.jpg`, and try to include that, it works as well.

### ensure I (or pdflatex) has sufficient rights

If I run

```bash
$ ls -l ./texmf-project/tex
drwxrwxrwx 1 user user 4096 May 10 11:20 images
```

I am led to believe that `pdflatex` run by user should be able to create the converted pdf file.

## Asking for help

Why is this not working as intended, i.e. what am I doing wrong? How can I make use of the image located inside my custom texmf-tree?

Comment: epstopdf can't convert eps from a texmf tree on the fly. Convert the eps with `epstopdf logo.eps` to pdf and put the pdf in your local tree too.

Comment: Isn't it just easier (and safer) to manually convert the image instead of relying on an auto convert feature?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer That's a bummer. I would have liked to rely on the eps files only. I tried your suggestion, of course, and as predicted, converting manually and placing the pdf inside the texmf-tree works.

Comment: @daleif Since this is not only for me, I'd rather rely on an autoconvert feature than rely on the users needing to manually convert, if there should ever be changes to the eps file, which is given to me.

Comment: I don't think that is a good idea in case something goes wrong, user using a bad ghostscript version etc. I'd stay away from auto conversion as much as possible.

Comment: like @daleif I think it is much safer if you provide a suitable image  (and I wouldn't call it logo, my test folder is full of various logo images.)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I think it's safe to trust your superior expertise as well as daleif's. Regarding your additional concern, I just renamed the file for the sake of this MWE. In reality, it has a cumbersome, long but meaningful name.

Actually, coming from windows, I was under the impression that eps files could be included directly without any conversion. That is why I had a preference for eps files.